# Looping a rolling-window regression with a NA values

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression

an R-programming problem here.

So I am trying to run multiple rolling-window regressions and saving the betas for each regression. In my given example I want to regress Y on X1 for the first 5 obs. Then save the beta (slope coefficient). Then run on the next 5 (so Row 2 to Row 6) and save the next beta. I want to do this three times for my different X values. 
My data looks something as follows:

```
Row Y X1 X2 X3 
 1  1  2  3  NA
 2  1  3  5  NA
 3  1  4  6  NA
 4  2  4  6  4
 5  3  3  4  8
 6  4  4  6  7 
 7  3  5  5  3
 8  5  4  6  7
```

The code I am trying to run is a loop and is as follows:

```
#Rows equals the number of rows in my obs matrix.
for (j in 1:3) {
  for (i in 1:(Rows-4)) {
    Model<- lm(data[((i+0):(4+i)),1] ~ data[((i+0):(4+i)),j])
    betas[i,j] <- coefficients(Model)[2]
  }
}
```

The problem is that my beta matrix gives me only NAs for the third column of X3. So what I am getting is:

```
Row X1     X2   X3 
 1  coef  coef  NA
 2  coef  coef  NA
 3  coef  coef  NA
 4  coef  coef  NA
```

However, what I would like to get is something along the following lines:

```
#my beta matrix looks like this

Row X1     X2   X3 
 1  coef  coef  NA
 2  coef  coef  NA
 3  coef  coef  NA
 4  coef  coef  coef
```

In other words, because that last column (X3) has some initial NAs it is giving me NAs for all future coefficient values even when the window it is regressing on is NA free. I have tried messing around with na.omit commands to no avail.

Does anyone have a solution as to how to conduct this looped regression? 
Very grateful already. All the best

Comment: How are you initializing `betas`? As an empty numeric matrix? Also, `i+0` is redundant.

Comment: Forgive me, I am not quite sure what you mean.  I am just saving the slope coefficient into a new matrix.

Comment: Your code omits lines. As of now `betas` (even `Rows`) does not exist. Show its line of creation before loop. Maybe `betas <- matrix(...)`.

Comment: beta = matrix( NA , nrow = 4 , ncol = 3) 
Rows = nrow(data)
Does this help?

Comment: One issue might be that your inner `for` loop uses just one row, check `for (i in 1:(Rows-4)) {print(i)}`.

Answer (score 0):

We could do an `outer` approach to apply an arbitrary function to all combinations of the elements two objects (lists/vectors).

We'll need a `row.list` of increasing sequences of five,

```
row.list <- lapply(1:(nrow(dat)-4), function(x) x:(x+4))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 4 5 6 7 8
```

and a vector `ev` of our explanatory variables.

```
ev <- c("X1", "X2", "X3")
```

We also need our `regFUN` which uses `reformulate` to create formulae from strings,

```
regFUN <- Vectorize(function(x, i) lm(reformulate(x, "Y"), dat[i, -1])$coe[2])
```

and which we finally apply on all combinations of the elements our two objects using `outer`.

```
res <- t(outer(ev, row.list, regFUN))
```

### Result

```
`colnames<-`(res, ev)
#                X1          X2        X3
# [1,] 1.428571e-01 -0.05882353 0.2500000
# [2,] 3.333333e-01 -0.12500000 0.3461538
# [3,] 1.648597e-15 -0.37500000 0.1764706
# [4,] 0.000000e+00  0.37500000 0.2872340
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(text="Row Y X1 X2 X3 
 1  1  2  3  NA
 2  1  3  5  NA
 3  1  4  6  NA
 4  2  4  6  4
 5  3  3  4  8
 6  4  4  6  7 
 7  3  5  5  3
 8  5  4  6  7", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am a little confused by the final output where the NAs appear to be in different spots than the betas that I had hoped for. I think you are thinking that I am running a model that looks like Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3  when I am actually trying to separately perform a regression that looks like Y ~ X1 and save the beta, then Y ~ X2 and then save the beta, then Y ~ X3 and save the beta. Then adjust the window and regress again.

Comment: The coefficients may also be `NA` for other reasons such as [collinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25806/163114). Just noticed you want the betas matrix without intercept, I therefore edited  `0 +` in the formula.

Comment: Hi, that is true. but collinearity would only be a problem if i am regressing on more than one independent variable which I am not.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by your output again. It seems like you are including all three vairables in the regression. I would like to have them calculated separately. 
So I run the following 4 times and then save the betas 4 times (each time has a new window of data)
Y ~ X1 
Then I do the same for X2 and X3 however for X3 because of NAs I should not get iniiial values. This should give me the following:
```
Row X1     X2   X3 
 1  coef  coef  NA
 2  coef  coef  NA
 3  coef  coef  NA
 4  coef  coef  coef
```

Comment: Sorry, I really missed that you use bivariate models. Check my edits to the answer. I don't get NA, though; `lm` uses case-wise deletion, so e.g. in regressions of rows `1:5` on variable `X3`, actually just rows `4:5` are used.

Answer (score 0):

Issue comes down to your column referencing with *j*. Since you need to fill in an empty matrix but ignore first column in *data* add a 1 to skip first column used as dependent variable. And because of your window at 4 being larger than `NA` rows at 3, there should be regression results for all rows:

```
for (j in 1:3) {
  for (i in 1:(Rows-4)) {
    Model<- lm(data[i:(4+i),1] ~ data[i:(4+i), j+1])
    betas[i,j] <- coefficients(Model)[2]
  }
}

betas
#              [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 1.428571e-01 -0.05882353 0.2500000
# [2,] 3.333333e-01 -0.12500000 0.3461538
# [3,] 1.648597e-15 -0.37500000 0.1764706
# [4,] 0.000000e+00  0.37500000 0.2872340
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/HZXCW96318)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. The issue was that an error message was shown once I started to compute the final columns (X3s) regression.

The code that provided the right solution was as follows:

```
for (j in 1:3) {
  for (i in 1:(Rows-4)) {
    try(Model<- lm(data[i:(4+i),1] ~ data[i:(4+i), j+1]), silent=T)
    betas[i,j] <- coefficients(Model)[2]
  }
}
```

The inclusion of try allowed me to continue running the loop and attain the final value in the last column. Thanks everyone for your help.